# quotient of sums based on different selector fields

Tags: tableau-api

I try to solve a problem that I have with Tableau actually.

I have one big data view base on requests.

For every request I have the request time, a person that works on it (Assignee) and the amount of time he worked on it (WorkedHours)
In this record there is also a field QAAssignee and QATime which hold another employee and how much time he spent for QA.

I have another view with all users in it and the daily capacity ( e.g 8hours)

Now I would like to do a list of all possible people in that view (assignee) and QAAssignee grouped by year, month with the usage of her/his time.

So it should be (Time s/he used to work on a request + time s/he use to do QA) / Aavailable time.

How can I achieve that in Tableau?

Thanks in advance for every hint.

Comment: If you add a link to dummy data, you will have a better chance.